# Error de enrutamiento usando Angular - Spring Boot en Weblogic

Tags: spring, angular, weblogic

Creé un proyecto Spring Boot Rest, el cual consumo desde una aplicación angular.
Construyo el war con maven, lo subo a WebLogic y funciona perfectamente, siempre  cuando la ruta configurada en el weblogic.xml sea "/", si le asigno un nombre a la ruta por ejemplo "/webapp" no consigo visualizar el front en WebLogic, al ejecutar el index, me sale error 404, porque no encuentra los archivos, no sé si para que se puede realizar esa visualización es necesaria una configuración en angular, o en Spring o en Weblogic, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: En tomcat para que una aplicación aparezca en `localhost:8080/` es necesario que el war se llame `ROOT.war`, de otra manera aparece en la ruta `localhost:8080/nombredemiapp/` Intenta cambiar el nombre del war de tu aplicación a `webapp.war` para ver si funciona de la misma manera.

Comment: Estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con Tomcat, y supuse sería igual, pero WebLogic, tiene configuración adicional y no es tan automático. Sin embargo no he sabido cómo cargar las views en el lugar donde se despliegue el war. 

PD: Intenté lo que me dijiste, y no fue exitoso.

Comment: Según esta documentación http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/03-DeployApps/deployapps.htm debería funcionar como te lo digo, igual me estoy perdiando algo. Revisala haber si algo sacas de ahí.

Comment: Usé exactamente ese tutorial para realizar el despliegue.

Comment: Vaya tristeza! Si encuentras una solución la publicas por que estas son las cosas que lo frustran a uno. Por cierto. ¿Si trabajas con tomcat por qué no vuelves a él? ¿Es requisito usar weblogic? A lo mejor te ahorras bastante tiempo.

Comment: Es requisito empresarial -.-